# How can I change login error messages on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to change displayed text when there's an error while someone is trying to login on my website. I found where are the current displayed messages that I'd like to change. They are on the user.php file (`wp-includes/user.php`).

Specifically:

```
function wp_authenticate_email_password( $user, $email, $password ) {
if ( $user instanceof WP_User ) {
    return $user;
}

if ( empty( $email ) || empty( $password ) ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return $user;
    }

    $error = new WP_Error();

    if ( empty( $email ) ) {
        $error->add( 'empty_username', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The email field is empty.' ) ); // Uses 'empty_username' for back-compat with wp_signon()
    }

    if ( empty( $password ) ) {
        $error->add( 'empty_password', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password field is empty.' ) );
    }

    return $error;
}

if ( ! is_email( $email ) ) {
    return $user;
}

$user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

if ( ! $user ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'invalid_email',
        __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid email address.' ) .
        ' <a href="' . wp_lostpassword_url() . '">' .
        __( 'Lost your password?' ) .
        '</a>'
    );
}
```

And

```
if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return $user;
    }

    if ( ! wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password',
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: email address */
                __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the email address %s is incorrect.' ),
                '<strong>' . $email . '</strong>'
            ) .
            ' <a href="' . wp_lostpassword_url() . '">' .
            __( 'Lost your password?' ) .
            '</a>'
        );
    }

    return $user;
}
```

I think I should use `add_filter`on my `functions.php`file in my child theme but I`m not familiar with it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress had already given option for changing error text, you can do it using functions.php

Follow this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_errors

Comment: Thanks for answering! When I use that example code and someone digits a wrong password or username I have as result a blank page.

Comment: You are welcome, did you checked by enabling debug mode? 
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);` in your config file.
It will show you the actual error instead of white screen

Comment: I've enabled debug mode. It says: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_error_codes() on null in /home/myusername/mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/shop-isle-child/functions.php on line 77`. Line 77 on my `functions.php` is: `$err_codes = $errors->get_error_codes();`. What should I have to do?

Comment: I simply copied the example code in the page you provided to me and I pasted it as it is on my `functions.php`. Thanks again for your interest! :D

Answer (score 0):

Function.php is the way to override the error messages.

you can do that using login_errors filter hook and here is how:

add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');

```
function login_error_message($error){
    //check if that's the error you are looking for
    $pos = strpos($error, 'incorrect');
    if (is_int($pos)) {
        //its the right error so you can overwrite it
        $error = "Wrong information";
    }
    return $error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I've already tested that code and it doesn't change anything!